# Why this java code doesn't get last updated ID?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I was getting last inserted ID from below code but as I changed it for update it always returns me 0 as last updated ID. Is there any different way to get last Updated id in java using prepared statements?

```
public static String updateRegistrationInfo(Integer COMPANY_ID, String FIRST_NAME, String LAST_NAME, String MOBILE_NO,
                                       String WORK_EMAIL, String PASSWORD) throws Exception {
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    Integer last_inserted_id = 0;

    String insertTableSQL = 
        "UPDATE USER_DETAILS SET COMPANY_ID=?,FIRST_NAME=?, LAST_NAME=?, MOBILE_NO=?, WORK_EMAIL=?, PASSWORD=? WHERE WORK_EMAIL=? AND MOBILE_NO=?";

    try {

        dbConnection = getConnection();

        //--USER_ID IS SET TO AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

        String returnCols[] = { "USER_ID" };

        //--INSERTING MEETING DETAILS

        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL, returnCols);

        preparedStatement.setInt(1, COMPANY_ID);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, FIRST_NAME);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, LAST_NAME);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, MOBILE_NO);
        preparedStatement.setString(5, WORK_EMAIL);
        preparedStatement.setString(6, PASSWORD);
        preparedStatement.setString(7, WORK_EMAIL);
        preparedStatement.setString(8, MOBILE_NO);

        // execute insert SQL stetement
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (rs.next()) {
            last_inserted_id = rs.getInt(1);
        }

        return last_inserted_id.toString();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return e.getMessage() + " ERROR CODE: " + e.getErrorCode();
    } finally {
        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
            dbConnection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: Oracle supports returning clause, but it is not straightforward to use from JDBC. The JDBC standard does not support it.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `INSERT` which makes new rows, `UPDATE` operates on existing rows, and therefore it does not generate new row keys. When you make this call

```
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
   last_inserted_id = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

the result comes back empty, so `last_inserted_id` remains zero.

The logic behind this is simple: in the `INSERT` you do not know what the key is going to be, so JDBC lets you retrieve it. In the `UPDATE` you know what key you are setting - it's the `COMPANY_ID`, - so you do not need a way to retrieve it back.